# Передать массив в функцию как список аргументов

Tags: javascript

Необходимо обработать массив перед передачей в функцию так, чтобы каждый его элемент был отдельным аргументом.

Метод `.join` не помогает, так как он превращает объект в `[object Object]`.

Как это лучше всего сделать, учитывая то, что размер массива не фиксирован и может изменяться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Древний способ - [`fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function fun(a,b,c,d) {
  console.log(a,b,c,d);
}
fun(1,2,3,4);
// вот в такой форме передается массив:
fun.apply(this, [1,2,3,4]);
```

Первый параметр `apply()` (`thisArg`) задает значение `this` внутри функции:

```
var obj = { test: function fun(a) { console.log(this, a) } }
obj.test(1); // при вызове функции через '.', this в ней равен obj
obj.test.apply(obj, [1]); // при использовании apply нужно вручную передавать значение this
```

---

В ES6 появился [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), который позволяет обойтись без apply, но это в светлом будущем:

```
fun(...[5,6,7,8])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это работает!